# read the whole binary into a buffer then resolve it in specific format

Tags: c++, binary, buffer

Here is my C++ homework. Given a binary file, this file consists of some data units. Every data unit contains two parts. The first part is 1 `char` and the second part is 1 `int`. Read the whole file into a buffer at a time and then extract all data units from the buffer.
Now I've read the file into a buffer successfully like this:

```
char* readBinaryFile(const char* fileName) {
    ifstream file(fileName, ios::binary || ios::ate);

    // get the size of file
    streampos beg, end;
    beg = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0,ios::end);
    end = file.tellg();
    long size = end - beg;

    char* buffer = new char[size];

    // now read the file into buffer
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    file.read(buffer, size);
    file.close();

    return buffer;
}
```

So my problem is how can I get the data unit from the buffer?

Comment: Try looking into your buffer with the debugger to see if you get any ideas.

Comment: I've tried this but all I can see is some hexadecimal.@johnelemans

Comment: @maxwellhertz: Check the value of `size`. I'd bet it is `0`.

Comment: No the value of `size` is the same as the actual size of the file. I've checked it carefully.@Swordfish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write the code for you, but think about this for a moment...

At `buffer[0]` is your first char. At `buffer[1]` through `buffer[4]` is your first int. It repeats, so `buffer[5]` is the character for the second set of data.

There are five bytes for the character and the int together. If you know the amount of data you've read, you could divide that by 5 and know the number of "sets" of data there is.

You can now use something like a `for` loop to iterate from zero to the numbers of sets minus one. Let's say this iterator variable is `i`, then you could access the character of each "set" of data with `buffer[i * 5]`, the first byte of the int at `buffer[i * 5 + 1]`, etc.

So, a for loop and a little bit of math will help you extract the information from that buffer. You'll have 5 individual bytes, and you'll need to reassemble 4 of those bytes back into an int. There are a variety of ways of accomplishing this, which I'll let you attempt to discover.

Comment: Can I ask a more question? How can I convert a char array to an integer? I've searched a lot but I still get stuck in this.

Comment: Perhaps search Google, or even better, use the search bar at the top of this page. I just tried searching stackoverflow.com for "convert a char array to an integer" and the results look promising.

Answer (score 0):

Could your issue stem from the fact that you're using:

```
ios::binary || ios::ate
```

when I think you mean:

```
ios::binary | ios::ate
```

The former evaluates to "1", since binary logical-or at-end is "true", the latter is a bitmask that says "open this file in binary mode, and at the end". The way you have written it is actually the equivalent of

```
ios::app
```